# R Mutate Time Using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to find the mean time using dplyr and grouping by V1

```
y <- x %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(V2=mean(chron(times = V2))) %>%
as.data.frame(y)
```

Gives an error

```
Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

Sample Data Give Below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
V1  V2
a   8:12:29
a   8:19:39
a   8:25:32
b   8:30:19
b   8:30:44
b   8:31:18
c   8:32:52
c   8:32:58
d   9:03:50
d   9:06:02
d   9:06:57
d   9:08:27
e   9:59:45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  type_convert() %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(mean_time = mean(V2)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 13 x 3
      V1       V2       mean_time
   <chr>   <time>          <time>
 1     a 08:12:29 08:19:13.333333
 2     a 08:19:39 08:19:13.333333
 3     a 08:25:32 08:19:13.333333
 4     b 08:30:19 08:30:47.000000
 5     b 08:30:44 08:30:47.000000
 6     b 08:31:18 08:30:47.000000
 7     c 08:32:52 08:32:55.000000
 8     c 08:32:58 08:32:55.000000
 9     d 09:03:50 09:06:19.000000
10     d 09:06:02 09:06:19.000000
11     d 09:06:57 09:06:19.000000
12     d 09:08:27 09:06:19.000000
13     e 09:59:45 09:59:45.000000
```

You can also play around with `lubridate` to change the formatting if you'd like. For example:

```
df$mean_time <- lubridate::hms(df$mean_time)

# A tibble: 13 x 3
      V1       V2         mean_time
   <chr>   <time>      <S4: Period>
 1     a 08:12:29 8H 19M 13.333333S
 2     a 08:19:39 8H 19M 13.333333S
 3     a 08:25:32 8H 19M 13.333333S
 4     b 08:30:19        8H 30M 47S
 5     b 08:30:44        8H 30M 47S
 6     b 08:31:18        8H 30M 47S
 7     c 08:32:52        8H 32M 55S
 8     c 08:32:58        8H 32M 55S
 9     d 09:03:50         9H 6M 19S
10     d 09:06:02         9H 6M 19S
11     d 09:06:57         9H 6M 19S
12     d 09:08:27         9H 6M 19S
13     e 09:59:45        9H 59M 45S
```